# Firefox has trouble connecting to web pages

Tags: firefox

I have been on a vacation for about ten days and after I returned I found Firefox in a terrible state. It seems to have no problems connecting to some of the "bigger" web pages like google, gmail, facebook, etc. However, other pages like ebay, askubuntu.com, an most of the other web pages load either extremely slowly, or fail to load at all (and I have to re-try several times). I think the problem lies in establishing a connection with the page for some reason, but I have no idea what could be the cause (especially since nobody uses my computer and it worked quite well before).

Comment: Sound like you have some kind of network problems. I guess you already have tried to power off your own computer. I guess you are using a wifi connection try reboot your wifi router. You could try to ping google dns from a terminal window `ping 8.8.8.8` - you should se a stable ping time - within few microseconds. I often use the program `mtr` to diagnose such problems. Try 'mtr 8.8.8.8` then you are able to see if you lost any packet on the way.

Comment: I tried to use both cable and wifi alike. Ping on 8.8.8.8 is good 26.9-28.1ms is the range. Most comonly it is at 27.0. I tried restarting both my computer and my router several times. I really would like to avoid a hard (full?) reset on my rooter as it would probably scerw up my home network.

Comment: Is this issue Firefox-only? How about other browsers like Chrome, or lynx?

Comment: Did you clear up the cache?

Comment: I currently have no other browsers and, since I am a beginner with Ubuntu, I have no idea how to clean or locate the cache...

Comment: Sounds very similar to this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/956139